# JS Canvas has lines beside grids drawn

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I have a game I'm working on that is grid based. I noticed if the window is a certain width, then the grids will have vertical lines separating them. Below I attached two images, one with the screen at 905px (with lines) and another with the screen at 906px (without lines). It alternates between lines or no lines every 3 to 4px.

[image: With Lines]
[image: Without Lines]

There is an online version located here - [Game Link](https://rtsws.herokuapp.com/)

Any possibly explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your images are not completely filling in the space. If this is the case, try drawing the images with 1-2 pixel overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm going to look further into it but it appears the grids shrink/grow slightly although I never resize them in the code. Setting it wider doesn't fix it, I'll post here if I figure out the resizing cause.